# Determine perimeter of a complex plane

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I need help that how can I calculate the complete perimeter / area of this image? when every square has 2 meter of length. 
[image: perimeter]

Comment: The sides that are parallel to the axes you can count the little squares. The side that is diagonal use Pythagoras on a triangle that has that side as hypotenuse and the other two side parallel to the axes. Those two other sides have 4 and 5 squares in length respectively. By Pythagoras the diagonal side will have length $\sqrt{4^2+5^2}$ little squares. Finally, the circular part is 3/4 of the total perimeter of the circle. The circle has radius 2 little squares. Therefore it has total perimeter $2\times 2\times\pi$ little squares. Therefore $3\times2\times2\times\pi/4$ little squares.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Hellen!

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the figure in four different parts.
[image]